# I've changed GRUB_DEFAULT value from 0 to 1 and it made ubuntu boot to the recovery mode

Tags: grub2

Since then I Ubuntu can't start. Even after I go to "resume" in the recovery mode, it keeps leaving me a black screen.

Another thing, when booting, Ubuntu shows something like "error NTFS preset"

Comment: You should ask about the NTFS problem in another question.

Answer (score 1):

> I've changed GRUB_DEFAULT value from 0 to 1 and it made Ubuntu boot to the recovery mode

The solution is simple:

1. In the recovery mode select "Drop to a root shell" (I believe they changed the wording, but it's almost the same).
2. Type `nano /etc/default/grub`
3. Look for the line that reads `GRUB_DEFAULT`
4. Change the `1` to `0`.
5. Press Ctrl + O, now press Enter.
6. Press Ctrl + X.
7. Type `update-grub`.
8. Type `reboot`. Now you should be booting to Ubuntu normally.

The "Resume Ubuntu" was not intended to take you to a full GUI boot but to a login prompt. The modules in Recovery Mode aren't loaded fully as they should assure the maximum compatibility with any video card. Hence if you want a Normal Boot the best way is starting Ubuntu without using the "Resume boot" option.

Comment: It should be noted that GRUB counts with `0` as the first value, so the 2nd menu entry (position `1`) is the recovery option, hence this problem.

Comment: GRUB_DEFAULT is 0 already, but ubuntu still won't boot correctly.

Thanks